Resillience against timeouts and network instability
I'm trying to set up Oauth2 authentication with JWT tokens on my Spring boot 3 applications.
Unfortunately due to some instability on the network, i'm receiving very rarely:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "{insert-keycloak-issuer-link-here}"

   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:178)
...

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "{insert-keycloak-issuer-link-here}/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection timed out

I have run some test calling this link and I do indeed see sometimes it's unavailble for a random amount of seconds.
My question is if i'm limited to only tweak on the connection timeout settings for the resttemplate that Nimbus is using or if there are other configuration settings i've over looked.
I've been trying to investigate the documentation from
Oauth2.0 Resource server
I feel this sort of functionality is something the library should be able to handle, but this might just be me being lazy, I can implement my own retry functionality, but it just seems strange that Oauth2 doesn't have anything like this on it's own.
Previously before upgrading to Spring boot 3, I was using the keycloak libraries available and didn't run into anything problems regarding these urls being unavailble. (So i assume/guess, that keycloak libraries for spring was handling this behind the scenes for me.)

Your authorization server not answering for seconds is a problem, and not only for resource servers. This is where I'd put my energy into. Maybe you face this only at startup? Do you have something waiting for Keycloak to be correctly started before launching clients and resource servers?

Thank you for the comment. This is not a startup issue. Everytime a request is incomming, the token is being validated and the jwt decoder requests the current keycloak configuration to validate and process the token.
That endpoint is where i get my timeouts. Question is if i should go to my devops team and tell them to fix the instability (if they have time) or if I should make work arounds in my application fix this issue.

High availability on your authorization server is something you definitely need in prod for user and client's auth, exchange of code for tokens, tokens refreshing, new public keys fetching after JWT signing keys rotation,... Fetching OpenID conf really looks like a client and resource server startup issue (as opposed to what I list above)
